# Firebase Phone Auth Error : OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED for some regions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

I have been using Firebase Phone Auth since couple of months and my users base in mainly from india  and other middle east nation, feature was working find till couple of days suddenly stopped working  for middle east region. Still working for indian numbers though.

here  are some screenshot to know more about the error [image][image]

Did Trying disabling and removing provider, still no luck.

Comment: As much as possible, on Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.